# AngularJS directive two way binding for a configurable number of variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When creating a directive, while defining isolate scope with two way binding using `=` is there any way that I can bind an array of scope variables. ie. if in my controller I have objects defined like `$scope.one`, `$scope.two` etc. and there can be any number of those - I want the directive to be able to handle a configurable number of them. How could I do that?

I can't do this, since another controller that uses the directive may have ten, so I want it to be flexible:

```
.directive("example", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
          one: "=",
          two: "=",
          three: "="
        },
    ...
```

Comment: You have the `attrs` (attributes) object for that, but you should pass an object with as many properties as you want to the directive's scope - This is the preferred method to handle this

Comment: Do you need the variables for one-off use (or) do you need your array of variables to have 2-way binding so that every time the variable value inside your directive changes, it should reflect in your main controller ?

Comment: Why use so many individual scope variables and not pass through as one object?

Comment: I do need two way binding. I have $watch statements set up for $one, $two etc. in the controller so if I change any of them I want a function to trigger in the controller.

Comment: @user648931 You can watch an object too, trust me - Use object, much more ease to handle and simplify the code making it more manageable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course it is:

```
.directive('example', function() {
   return {
     scope: {
       config: '='
     },
     link: function(scope) {
       var firstOption = scope.config[0];
       var secondOption = scope.config[1];
       //...
     }
   }
}
```

The array options would have to be stored at a fixed index, so it would be less readable than passing a config *object*

```
.directive('example', function() {
       return {
         scope: {
           config: '='
         },
         link: function(scope) {
           var firstOption = scope.config.firstOption;
           var secondOption = scope.config.secondOption;
           //...
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Better to also use [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) to set default values to unset propertes with a default value, but it's a good answer

Comment: Ah, thanks, this makes sense - I'll try it this way.